# Error on SharePoint 2013 farm configuration

Tags: sharepoint, configuration, sharepoint-2013

I face a problem with the SharePoint 2013 farm configuration. I'd like to create a new server farm, but failed to complete product configuration of SharePoint 2013. After following configuration wizard steps, I'm getting the following error message:

[image]

My SQL Server version is

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) 
    Apr  2 2010 15:48:46 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

Minimum requirements for a database server in a farm for SharePoint 2013 is one of the following:

- 64-bit edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2012,
- 64-bit edition of SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1.

The error message on your screenshot says *"SQL server has an unsupported version 10.50.1600.1"*. And that's exactly the SQL Server version you're using (64-bit edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1). Please try to update your database server to see if it resolves your issue.

Reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx